# Download attribute doesn't not working for remote url server

Tags: html

Download attribute doesn't not working for remote url server.

```
<a download="download_html_file.html" href="http://jsfiddle.net/">download jsfiddle html</a>
```

Downloaded file whithout name "download_html_file.html"

If

```
<a download="download_html_file.html" href="/">download jsfiddle html</a>
```

file save as "download_html_file.html"

What to do? How fix this?

I need download file with name "download_html_file.html" from url jsfiddle.net (remote url (with http))

http://jsfiddle.net/gq3t7vfu/1/

Comment: What are you expecting to happen? I don't understand.

Comment: I need download file with name  "download_html_file.html" from url http://jsfiddle.net/ (remote url (with http))